# How do I get the bounds of a JPanel centered in another JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have a main panel with a border layout containing another panel in the center.
Because I want to paint inside the centered panel I have to get the bounds of it.

```
panel_main.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

I wanted to save the bounds in a rectangle like this:

```
Rectangle bounding = new Rectangle 
   (panel.getX(), panel.getY(), panel.getWidth(), panel.getHeight());
```

But every argument seems to be 0. So how do I get the bounds of the panel?
Could I get the bounds of the BorderLayout instead?

Comment: I am not sure you need the bounds. If you do,get the bounds after layout is invoked (after `pack()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But every argument seems to be 0.

All Swing components have a size of (0, 0) when they are created. Components are only given a size when the frame is packed and made visible.

> Because I want to paint inside the centered panel I have to get the bounds of it.

You override the `paintComponent()` method of the panel. Then you can use the `getSize()` method to control where the painting is done.

You will also need to override the `getPreferredSize()` method of the panel so the layout manager can pack() the frame properly.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples to get you started.

Comment: But after I added it to the main panel (like the example above), it should have a size right?